# Angular.js Google tutorial not working for me

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner in Angular.js, so I have decided to try a Google tutorial, and I just don't understand why this error keep occurring. I searched for the solution in Stack Overflow, and most of the people said to take off the"gemStore" in my ng-app, but I tried that too and it didn't work as well:

```
angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=gemStore&p1=Error%3…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.1%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4759
    at q (angular.js:357)
    at g (angular.js:4720)
    at eb (angular.js:4642)
    at c (angular.js:1838)
    at Mc (angular.js:1859)
    at pe (angular.js:1744)
    at angular.js:32977
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3314)
```

What can I do to fix it?

JS code:

```
 (function() {
      var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

  app.controller('StoreController', function() {
    this.products = gems;
  });

  var gems = [{
    name: 'Azurite',
    description: "Some gems have hidden qualities beyond their luster, beyond their shine... Azurite is one of those gems.",
    shine: 8,
    price: 110.50,
    rarity: 7,
    color: '#CCC',
    faces: 14,
    images: [ ]
  }, {
    name: 'Bloodstone',
    description: "Origin of the Bloodstone is unknown, hence its low value. It has a very high shine and 12 sides, however.",
    shine: 9,
    price: 22.90,
    rarity: 6,
    color: '#EEE',
    faces: 12,
    images: [
      "images/gem-01.gif",
      "images/gem-03.gif",
      "images/gem-04.gif"
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Zircon',
    description: "Zircon is our most coveted and sought after gem. You will pay much to be the proud owner of this gorgeous and high shine gem.",
    shine: 70,
    price: 1100,
    rarity: 2,
    color: '#000',
    faces: 6,
    images: [
      "images/gem-06.gif",
      "images/gem-07.gif",
      "images/gem-09.gif"
    ]
  }];
})();
```

index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <!--  Products Container  -->
    <div class="list-group">
      <!--  Product Container  -->
      <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
        <h3>
          {{product.name}}
          <em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</em>
        </h3>

        <!-- Image Gallery  -->
        <div ng-show="product.images.length" class="gallery">
          <img class="img img-circle img-thumbnail center-block" ng-src="{{product.images[0]}}" />
          <ul class="clearfix">
            <li class="small-image pull-left thumbnail" ng-repeat="image in product.images"> <img ng-src="{{image}}" /> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, to have a more readable error message, use angular.js, not angular.min.js. Second, assuming your index.html file is loaded from `http://localhost:8080/index.html`, what happens when you go to `http://localhost:8080/app.js`? When you open your console, do you se any error? When goin to the network tab of your dev tools, do you see any HTTP request with an error code (like 404)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with parenthesis.

Your code just works, I tested it just now in Chrome and Firefox but you should avoid using single quote.
Double quotes is considered standard while single quote is not. http://www.json.org/

Could you provide more information like the browser/version you're using ?

Open a Chrome tab in private mode without any chrome extension and check if it still fails.

Edit: Are you sure that the app.js file contains only the code mentioned above?

If not, please provide the full content of app.js

Comment: omg, in private mode works! Sorry the dummy question, but why in private works? and many thanks!!!!

Comment: Maybe an extension is blocking a script. Deactivate them one by one and you'll find the guilty one ;)

Comment: i will never figure it out by myself hahaha. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: If you feel my answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have not closed the paranthesis correctly, alos assign this.gems = gems; at the bottom .

**DEMO**

```js
 (function() {
   var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

   app.controller('StoreController', function() {
     var gems = [{
       name: 'Azurite',
       description: "Some gems have hidden qualities beyond their luster, beyond their shine... Azurite is one of those gems.",
       shine: 8,
       price: 110.50,
       rarity: 7,
       color: '#CCC',
       faces: 14,
       images: []
     }, {
       name: 'Bloodstone',
       description: "Origin of the Bloodstone is unknown, hence its low value. It has a very high shine and 12 sides, however.",
       shine: 9,
       price: 22.90,
       rarity: 6,
       color: '#EEE',
       faces: 12,
       images: [
         "images/gem-01.gif",
         "images/gem-03.gif",
         "images/gem-04.gif"
       ]
     }, {
       name: 'Zircon',
       description: "Zircon is our most coveted and sought after gem. You will pay much to be the proud owner of this gorgeous and high shine gem.",
       shine: 70,
       price: 1100,
       rarity: 2,
       color: '#000',
       faces: 6,
       images: [
         "images/gem-06.gif",
         "images/gem-07.gif",
         "images/gem-09.gif"
       ]
     }];
     
     this.products = gems;
   });
 
 })();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>  
 
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <!--  Products Container  -->
    <div class="list-group">
      <!--  Product Container  -->
      <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
        <h3>
          {{product.name}}
          <em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</em>
        </h3>

        <!-- Image Gallery  -->
        <div ng-show="product.images.length" class="gallery">
          <img class="img img-circle img-thumbnail center-block" ng-src="{{product.images[0]}}" />
          <ul class="clearfix">
            <li class="small-image pull-left thumbnail" ng-repeat="image in product.images"> <img ng-src="{{image}}" /> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have copied all your code, but still the same error :/

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira whats not working?https://plnkr.co/edit/fHW7ojki3srt1xQtLeYc?p=preview download this and run